# postgreSQL json query and update/insert

Tags: postgresql

I have json like this that based on the value of the enabled variable I want to insert into a table.

```
    {
         "Name": "Shop1",
        "Id": "1",
        "enabled": false
      
    },
    {
        "Name": "Shop2",
        "Id": "2",
        "enabled": true
    }
    
   
]
```

In a query I would like to select any items that are true and insert into a table. The table schema I want to insert into looks like

id,enabled

how to query the json and push into the rows of the other table?

Comment: actually 11. mistakenly selected that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements()` for that:

```
insert into the_table (id, enabled)
select (e ->> 'Id')::int, 
       (e ->> 'enabled')::boolean
from jsonb_array_elements('[
                             {"Name": "Shop1","Id": "1","enabled": false},
                             {"Name": "Shop2","Id": "2","enabled": true}
                           ]') as t(e)
where e ->> 'enabled' = 'true';
```